# Upgrading PopOS 21.10 to 22.04: simulated upgrade works but trying fails?

Tags: upgrade, pop-os

I am trying to upgrade pop os. I am following this tutorial:

https://support.system76.com/articles/upgrade-pop/

Finally got to step 6 and ran
`pop-upgrade release upgrade`

which said the simulated upgrade went fine. I rebooted my device and got an error. Trying to correct it via the command line:

```
$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdm3 : Depends: gir1.2-gdm-1.0 (= 41~rc-0ubuntu2pop0~1634915133~21.10~cf40258) but 42.0-1ubuntu6pop1~1650301427~22.04~2055533 is installed
        Depends: libgdm1 (= 41~rc-0ubuntu2pop0~1634915133~21.10~cf40258) but 42.0-1ubuntu6pop1~1650301427~22.04~2055533 is installed
 gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-common (= 40.0.1-1ubuntu3pop0~1639691325~21.10~3bcd31b) but 42.1-1ubuntu3pop0~1651657687~22.04~0386384 is installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 248.3-1ubuntu8.6~1650893010~21.10~9a0cd5e) but 249.11-0ubuntu3pop0~1650312774~22.04~cecf6af is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

So not sure what happened or how to fix it.